# What is the importance of Suvasinis

Tags: rituals, women

What is the importance of *Suvasinis* (married woman) in all Hindu rituals? Why not a widow or a celibate girl participate in Hindu rituals? What is the reason for giving coconut and rice only to *Suvasinis*? Please also explain science behind it (*if there is any*).

Comment: Asking for a scientific reason is considered off-topic on this site. For more information, you can refer this [meta post](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/142/124). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Why can't we ask about science prevalent in Hinduism? Hinduism without science is nothing. Many scientific things in Hinduism are called as superstition due to lack of awareness. They need to be cleared and this platform is good for that.

Comment: Asking like: "Any science behind it" will let users assume  to answer your post in pure scientific way. Try to edit it and make like "Please **also** explain the science behind this?". (_just for example_)

Comment: Mr_Green already informed you that the question is off-topic because we don't not provide scientific reason behind religion practices. Also your question has too many mini questions so make sure you edit and make it suitable for the site and later flag me for a reopen